# How to validate a user through an AJAX request?

Tags: php, ajax, authentication

We have a webpage that we provide to partner companies via an iFrame.  The iFrame contains several javascript files that make ajax requests to our server for data.  The iFrame itself requires an API Key that is keyed to the domain of the partner.  This prevents the iFrame from displaying if it is installed on a domain that isn't registered.  However, it would be pretty easy to simply copy the contents and javascript files of the iFrame from a registered site and host them on a non-registered site.

Ideally we'd like to use the API key to restrict Ajax requests and prevent our server from providing the requested data for non-registered sites.  However, it appears that the HTTP_REFERER server variable is not set for Ajax requests.  How can we tell what site that the request is coming from?  Is it possible?  If not, how can we prevent unauthorized access?

Answer (score 1):

Relying on HTTP_REFERER isn't the way to go.  You want your client's website to use an API to contact your website over a secure link, and get a temporary session string, which is then used as part of the source url for the IFRAME, which is how google does it (not with referer.)

Make the url for the IFRAME valid for a limited time, after which you display a nice message about going back to the client's page to start over.

Answer (score 0):

When the iframe is requested you can generate a unique ID on your server, then set that as a cookie on the client. Every AJAX request should contain that cookie. Only keep around the ID's for the last hour or so.

You can never rely on HTTP_REFERER because some proxy servers and firewalls will strip it out to preserve users' privacy.

Answer (score 0):

The challenge is that the iframe is authorized to a specific domain, so my API Key is tied to that.  I followed the following tutorial to generate my API keys.

https://ajax.dev.java.net/ajax/api-keys

Do you think that relying on the HTTP_REFERER variable will prevent users from accessing the iframe?  Sun claims that Google uses this method for Google Maps API authentication.

Once the API key has been authenticated, then the cookie approach should do the trick, I think.  Thanks!